# Composer generated installation can't be completely cloned

Tags: 8, version-control, composer

I have a Drupal 8 installation where I removed all Composer generated folders from the root .gitignore, so that I can make a complete clone of the installation. The problem is that module folders which contain a .git folder themselves remain empty in the cloned folder. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly explain on https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md

In short, that's because git kind of treats folders with a .git as submodules.

The composer.lock file exists to be able to re-install an exact copy with the same commits of dependencies and so on. Or another option is building .tar.gz, containers or similar packages that can be used for efficient deployments.

Comment: Ok, this topic is highly debated (https://www.codeenigma.com/build/blog/do-you-really-need-composer-production) and most articles and forum posts recommend not to use Composer on production. What is best practice if I want to follow this recommendation?

Comment: It's not recommended to run composer _update_ in production, but running composer _install_ **is** recommended. I read that article as well and I disagree with it. Unfortunately codeenigma does not allow comments on their blog and the author never responded to my questions about it. But the argument against that article is that the software world does not commit "builds" for space reasons and I prefer to remain consistent rather than have special processes for interpretive languages. I also don't like committing my transpiled javascript...

Comment: Sorry, I was not notified about your comment. It's the first time I hear about the different recommendations for update/install. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: different to what? what @mradcliffe described is the only way that I know of and i the reason why there is a composer.lock file. composer install installs exactly what is in there, guaranteed (as long as some external package isn't deleted or something like that) while update tries to use the most recent versions that match your constraints in composer.json.

Comment: I was just surprised to hear about the recommendation, because I mostly read before not to use Composer on production at all. What would happen in case that an external package is not available?

Comment: It would fail. It depends what you understand with "on production", a common practice is the mentioned directy switch with a symlink, if it fails, you abort the deployment, another is a process where you build a tar.gz and distribute that to your production server(s), which again gives you the option to abort if something fails. Neither of those options require you to commit everything to git.